# Program running as user can overwrite root file

Tags: permissions

I'm running Eclipse and trying to prevent it from changing a file automatically when it starts up. I thought setting the file to `root:root` with `-rw-rw-r--` permissions would have been enough but it appears to be changing the ownership back to my user and then editing the file regardless.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of playing around I worked out what Eclipse is doing. Feels like a rookie mistake but I figured I'd post the answer in case it trips others up.

It is reading the files, deleting the containing folder, recreating the folder and then recreating the files with the desired permissions.

File can be manipulated:

```
parentDir    user:user drwxrwxr-x
-> folder    user:user drwxrwxr-x
 -> file     root:root -rw-rw-r--
```

File is safe from user:

```
parentDir    user:user drwxrwxr-x
-> folder    root:root drwxrwxr-x
 -> file     root:root -rw-rw-r--
```

The above is safe because you need write access to a directory to delete it, whereas for a file you need write access to the containing directory to delete it.

Comment: A directory that I can not write to (delete from), and containing at least one file. Can not be removed by me.

Comment: That is true. If only the file is protected then the file can be edited by deleting the folder and replacing the file, but if the folder is protected then you cannot delete the folder by removing its parent. I'll update my answer to reflect that.